# Which device to install the bootloader should I choose?

Tags: linux-mint, windows, system-installation, dual-boot, uefi

I have an Acer Aspire E1 with Windows 8.1 installed from factory.

I need to install in dualboot the Linux Mint without formatting the computer and safely.

I kept the UEFI and deactivated the secureboot, and liberated 80GB from Windows.

However, I am in doubt on one of the installation steps. Which device should I install the bootloader? 
The options are:

- /dev/sda
- /dev/sda1
- /dev/sda2
- /dev/sda3
- /dev/sda4
- /dev/sda5

In the table above, have the following:

- /dev/sda1 | ntfs | 419mb total | 288MB used
- /dev/sda2 | efi | 314mb total | 52mb used.
- Windows is in / dev/sda4
- Free space (not inform the sda), is where I want to install Mint
- /dev/sda5 | 18.533mb total | 15.586mb used
- Free Space | 0mb total

Comment: Where is your [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) located, on sda4?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know.
The sda4 was what created from space reduction starting from Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming you are installing GRUB using the Mint installer in which case I recommend you not to touch it. Normally they are smart enough to know where to install themself. Now, for UEFI/EFI the bootloader/bootmanager should get installed in the efi partition `sda2` after being mounted as `boot/efi. This is consistent with what the [Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#UEFI_systems_2) says, through it warns that certain manufacturers could not work, in which case you will need to seek assistance.

Comment: In this case, installing GRUB in the same UEFI partition (sda2), the two will live together without killing each other? This is not dangerous because of what mode the computer will know who should run the default or GRUB?

Sorry to ask several questions, but I'm afraid to break the computer because it is not mine.

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks a lot. 
Whoever is reading this my question, may be good to read the topic that I had also created along with this question: http://forum.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=170010